# Position font awesome span icon above text within an anchor

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I'm trying to make some buttons with text positioned below a font awesome icon where both are positioned centrally inside a list item, and I need the anchor element, which also contains the span element for the font awesome icon, to fill the entire size of the list item.

I can fill the list item with the anchor no problem, but I'm having trouble positioning the icon's span above the text in the anchor that contains it.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qod142fz/.

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebarPrimary">

        <ul id="sidebarPrimaryNav">

            <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Home</a></li>

            <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>Personal Details</a></li>

            <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-briefcase"></span>Company</a></li>

            <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-gbp"></span>Invoices</a></li>

            <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-address-book"></span>Contacts</a></li>

            <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span>Expenses</a></li>

            <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-list"></span>Payslips</a></li>

            <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span>Settings</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* SIDEBAR PRIMARY */

#sidebarPrimary
{
position: fixed;
width: 15vw;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: #2F323E;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul > li.navButton
{
width: 100%;
height: 15vw;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul > li.navButton > a
{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: #687381;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 500;
transition: all linear 0.05s;
-webkit-transition: all linear 0.05s;
-moz-transition: all linear 0.05s;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul > li.navButton > a:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background: #E95656;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul > li.navButton > a > span
{
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is coming from `flex`. I recommend wrapping another `div` around the elements that should be centered inside the `a` tags

```css
/* SIDEBAR PRIMARY */

#sidebarPrimary {
    position: fixed;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #2F323E;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul > li.navButton {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vw;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul > li.navButton > a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #687381;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all linear 0.05s;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.05s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.05s;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul > li.navButton > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #E95656;
}

#sidebarPrimary > ul > li.navButton > a .fa {
    display: block;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="sidebarPrimary">
 <ul id="sidebarPrimaryNav">
  <li class="navButton"><a href="#">
   <div class="navButtonContent">
    <span class="fa fa-home"></span>Home
   </div>
  </a></li>
  <li class="navButton"><a href="#">
   <div class="navButtonContent">
    <span class="fa fa-user"></span>Personal Details
   </div>
  </a></li>
  <li class="navButton"><a href="#">
   <div class="navButtonContent">
    <span class="fa fa-briefcase"></span>Company
   </div>
  </a></li>
  <li class="navButton"><a href="#">
   <div class="navButtonContent">
    <span class="fa fa-gbp"></span>Invoices
   </div>
  </a></li>
  <li class="navButton"><a href="#">
   <div class="navButtonContent">
    <span class="fa fa-address-book"></span>Contacts
   </div>
  </a></li>
  <li class="navButton"><a href="#">
   <div class="navButtonContent">
    <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>Expenses
   </div>
  </a></li>
  <li class="navButton"><a href="#">
   <div class="navButtonContent">
    <span class="fa fa-list"></span>Payslips
   </div>
  </a></li>
  <li class="navButton"><a href="#">
   <div class="navButtonContent">
    <span class="fa fa-cog"></span>Settings
   </div>
  </a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#sidebarPrimary {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #2F323E;
}

#sidebarPrimary>ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#sidebarPrimary>ul>li.navButton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vw;
}

#sidebarPrimary>ul>li.navButton>a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #687381;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all linear 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.05s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.05s;
}

#sidebarPrimary>ul>li.navButton>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #E95656;
}

#sidebarPrimary>ul>li.navButton>a>span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarPrimary">

  <ul id="sidebarPrimaryNav">

    <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Home</a></li>

    <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>Personal Details</a></li>

    <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-briefcase"></span>Company</a></li>

    <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-gbp"></span>Invoices</a></li>

    <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-address-book"></span>Contacts</a></li>

    <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span>Expenses</a></li>

    <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-list"></span>Payslips</a></li>

    <li class="navButton"><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span>Settings</a></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position: absolute; top: 40px;` to font-awesome icons